# IP address character limit

Tags: wp-query, jquery, ip

my client in his template is using `<?php comment_author_IP(); ?>` to display IP's of comment authors. Recently he came to me with idea of limiting whole number to several characters. Final result should be something simillar to:

> 192.168...

How can i achieve it? I've tried with jquery but without success. It looked like it was not responding to the jquery code..

thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter `'get_comment_author_IP'`:

```
add_filter( 'get_comment_author_IP', 'wpse_77254_trim_comment_ip' );

function wpse_77254_trim_comment_ip( $ip )
{
    return implode( '.', array_slice(explode( '.', $ip ), 2) ) . '…';
}
```

Note this will fail with [IPv6 addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6).